# restore a missing Certificate Enrollment Requet

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2012

A csr was created through certreq and is not showing in the Certificate Enrollment Request store causing inability to complete the certificate.   I have tried importing the CSR into the Certificate Enrollment Request Store and get the file type is not recognizable.   Any suggestion on how to get the CSR into that folder would be appreciated

Comment: If CSR is not processed (i.e. signed) then you can create a new one. Make sure that you are looking in a correct store (Current User/Local Machine stores).